# unfortunately has stopped when selecting a listview item that starts a new activity

Tags: java, android

```
   05-11 05:27:07.932: D/AndroidRuntime(1297): Shutting down VM
05-11 05:27:07.932: W/dalvikvm(1297): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at com.example.carrentaladmin.AdminJSONParser.makeHttpRequest(AdminJSONParser.java:62)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at com.example.carrentaladminhonda.EditHondaActivity$GetProductDetails$1.run(EditHondaActivity.java:134)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-11 05:27:08.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm a beginner in android development and i totally don't understand these error log.I need you guys to help out.Hope you guys can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: i think you should use AsyncTask you cant do network call on main thread

Comment: Search for `NetworkOnMainThreadException` - you need to do network ops on a background thread such as `AsyncTask`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: You should show code, but I think this is the problem: NetworkOnMainThreadException

It must be that you have some network operation in main thread of the Activity you are trying to start. That is something you should not do and that is why you get this exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception?lq=1

Comment: But I'm using Asynctask..It works fine at first.But after i put this activity into tab layout., these errors occurred.Please help.Thanks

Comment: You have `runOnUiThread()` in your asynctask. Guess what it does?

Answer (score 3):

In android it is not a good practise to do network related operations on main thread of your activity.

For doing such things there are other methods like using AsyncTask.

Comment: @user3402438 you may refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html for the AsyncTask class reference.

Comment: But I'm using asyncTask.Then what's the problem actually?thank you

Comment: @user3402438 can you post your code?